# Center cell vertically in the navi bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center vertically the text in my menu bar. I have tried editing the HTML and CSS, but had no luck making it work.

The webpage is located at: http://www.xuanyinwen.com/test4.html
The CSS is at: http://www.xuanyinwen.com/css.css

Could anyone give some idea, please! Many thanks!

Comment: hey..you have a lot of question but still not have accepted answer. please click at the check mark if any answer usefull for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change **.vertical li a** to

```
.vertical li a{
border-color:-moz-use-text-color;
border-right:1px solid;
border-style:none solid solid;
border-width:0 1px 1px;
display:block;
line-height:4em;
padding:0.2em 10px;
text-decoration:none;
width:200px;
text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the anchor elements specific width and height (which is useless anyway, because they are given `display: block` already), you can give them a padding:

```
#menu li a {
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To your .vertical li a rule, add:

```
line-height: 4em;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: You do actually understand how `vertical-align` works, right? What `vertical-align` does is to change the alignment of inline element relative to the line box. The anchor already has `display: block` applied to them, so that line is useless. The `line-height` property is all that it takes for this to work.

Comment: Yes -- force of habit. Does no harm though, and my solution works.